# Conditional shebang for Git hooks cross platform

Tags: bash, git, githooks, shebang

In our projects we have developers who use windows and some use linux. We have githooks which uses shebang pointing to local windows shell executor, for example:

```sh
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

REGEX_ISSUE_ID="[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\_\-]+-[0-9]+"
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
ISSUE_ID=$(echo "$BRANCH_NAME" | grep -o -E "$REGEX_ISSUE_ID")
LAST_COMMIT_MSG=$(git show -s --format=%s)
```

As you can see the shebang is pointing to the windows folder. This would never work for linux users. Is there a better way of handling this to work cross platform?

Comment: Include a script in your repository that installs the git hooks, updating the shebang line as necessary?

Comment: Does `#!/bin/sh` not work? It should work in hooks on Windows, too.

Comment: As @j6t notes, `#! /bin/sh` suffices. Note also that `#! /usr/bin/env python` is a ridiculously common way to invoke Python scripts so I'd expect Windows exec to check for that too, though [Anthony Sottile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72291414/1256452) suggests it doesn't.

Comment: @torek I expect that `#!/usr/bin/env python` does not work when it occurs in a Git hook because `/usr/bin/env` is not a command interpreter of any kind. (Git stops at the first space when it is looking for the name of the command interpreter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at least for the top level git hook script (`.git/hooks/pre-commit` for example), git for windows will interpret the `#!/bin/sh` shebang and use a **bash** interpreter for the script.

if you then write posix-shell-compatible code in that script, it will be portable between windows and other posixly-correct machines

in my experience, writing posixly-correct shell is a bit of a pain so I *conditionally* install that script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on other platforms and `#!/bin/sh` on windows [source](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/e93c1c6f278b23f98f95c0e0706589f7932be298/pre_commit/commands/install_uninstall.py#L97-L102)

I'd then recommend explicitly calling out to other scripts as appropriate (python, etc.)